# Cut parts of subtitle file using FFMPEG

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, subtitle

I want to edit an input mp4 file with audio video subtitle streams, i can successfully cut video and audio streams by:
1- Convert each part to a new mp4 file
2- Convert mp4 files to mpg files

```
ffmpeg -i out00.mp4 -qscale:v 0 intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i out01.mp4 -qscale:v 0 intermediate2.mpg
```

3- Merge mpg files

```
ffmpeg -i concat:"intermediate1.mpg|intermediate2.mpg" -c copy intermediate_all.mpg
```

4- Convert the mpg file back to mp4

```
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg  -f mp4 output.mp4
```

and i can extract the subtitle stream to srt file, but i can't cut parts of the subtitle file, do you have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it works after long searching trip, here what i did:

1- Download latest FFMPEG from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (this was causing alot of problems for me).

2- Add the subtitle to the input files:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -i subtitles.srt -c copy -c:s srt -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -map 0 -map 1 -map_metadata 0 output.mkv
```

3- Cut the parts you need as you did normally ffmpeg will cut subtitle stream also

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:35 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -qscale:0:V 0 -y out0.mkv
```

4- Join the cut files using concat demux:

```
ffmpeg  -f concat -i mylist.txt  -c copy output.mkv
```

where mylist.txt contains:

file out0.mkv

file out1.mkv

And enjoy :).

Comment: So it has to be MKV! I tried before with MP4 and I was wondering why the sub wasn't getting trimmed. Although I know MP4 can contain subs but idk why it doesn't work. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to edit the srt manually (text and timecode the text needs to appear at) and remux it to your final video with a command like:

```
ffmpeg -i EditedSource.mp4 -i EditedSub.srt -c copy -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 1:s output.mp4
```

And instead of creating these intermediate files, have you tried:

```
ffmpeg -i out00.mp4 -i out01.mp4 -filter_complex '[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v][a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]'  output.mp4
```

Comment: i am trying to do this using ffmpeg not manual,
I will try the command to concat files and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: it works after few updates:
ffmpeg -i out0.mkv -i out1.mkv  -filter_complex "[0:0][0:1][0:2][1:0][1:1][1:2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v][a]" -map [v] -map [a]  -y output.mkv